# How can I update all documents in a collection to create a new field that replaces certain characters in an existing field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to add a new field called `searchname` to all documents based on the currently existing `name` but taking the string inside name and replacing all é with regular e. How can I do this in either the shell or a driver. I'm trying this in pymongo but I'm getting the error ```Invalid $set :: caused by :: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field``

Here is the code I'm trying to run

```
test_collection.update_many({},
    [{
        "$set": {
            "searchName": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": [
                        ["é", "e"],
                        ["à", "a"],
                        ["í", "i"],
                        ["ó", "o"],
                        ["ú", "u"],
                        ["ñ", "n"],
                    ],
                    "initialValue": {
                        "$toLower": "$name"
                    },
                    "in": {
                        "$replaceAll": {
                            "input": "$$value",
                            "find": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                    "$$this",
                                    0
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "replacement": {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                "$$this",
                                1
                            ]
                        }
        }}}}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query1

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
- you can use `$replaceAll` aggregate opertor
- for 1 character only

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=623271b0f7e3c64c6511e139)

```js
update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "searchName": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$name",
          "find": "é",
          "replacement": "e"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true})
```

Query2

- use this to replace many characters
- put your characters/replacements in the "input"

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49eb)

```js
update({},
[{"$set": 
   {"searchName": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": [["é", "e"], ["l", "k"]],
        "initialValue": "$name",
        "in": 
         {"$replaceAll": 
           {"input": "$$value",
            "find": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$this", 0]},
            "replacement": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$this", 1]}}}}}}}],
{"multi": true})
```

Comment: So can I put an array in the ```"find"``` field if I'm trying to replace multiple characters so if I wanted to replace é, á, í with e, a, i. Is that possible with this?

Comment: i updated the answer, added one more to do this for many

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/j4GeHvx_mIB Did I do this wrong? When I run it the second document doesn't have the ```searchName``` field.

Comment: no you did it fine, it was my fault you wanted updateMany, and i had it like updateOne,
i added `{multi :true}` you can use updateMany with your driver to do this in all documents

Comment: I'm running this in pymongo and I'm getting the error ```Invalid $set :: caused by :: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field```

Comment: probably your update method doesn't accept a pipeline(update pipeline are kinda new, the java driver supports it long time now), but you can always use it as [update command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) `update=collectionName` the `q={}`, `u=the pipeline above` also set `multi=true`
Maybe there is a way to avoid the command but i don't use pymongo to help more,read the docs on how to update with pipeline (i checked the API i didn't find method for this)